# Why react-select doesn't work with options from state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-select

This code works ok, because options are outside:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  };
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState(
      { selectedOption },
      () => console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedOption)
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.state.selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

but this code, doesn't work, because options are inside the state

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
     options: [
       { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
       { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
       { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
    ],
    selectedOption: null,
  };
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState(
      { selectedOption },
      () => console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedOption)
    );
  };
  render() {    
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.state.selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={this.state.options}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

If i use options from state, console log inside handleChange not return selectedOption.
Tell me please, why? 
I want to use this plugin with options from state...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `options = [` with `options: [`.